# JDK is updated but previous version is still getting shown as current version

Tags: java, configuration, installation, java-8

Previously in my machine, for

```
javac -version
```

I was getting

```
javac 1.6.0_65
```

I needed JDK 8 so I downloaded it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and installed it. But still I am getting the same version. But when I am running

```
`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 --exec javac -version`
```

I am getting

```
`javac 1.8.0_11`.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe again set the path ?

Answer (score 1):

When you install **Java 8** your previous Java versions (Java 6, Java 7) don't get uninstalled.

You need to:

1. Explicitly uninstall Java 6
2. Or, change your `JAVA_HOME` location. If you are using linux you could try: `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java` (at least in RH based distributions).

Comment: How I can run new java version, do I need to remove the previous version first?

Comment: Don't remove the previous version. You don't need to. Just follow my #2 step. What distro are you using?